# Dashing an area in a region plot where the region is not defined

Tags: regions

Can someone tell me how to dash a part of a region where the function doesn´t exist?

An example `1 >= x^2 + x > y`, where `y` is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) with `x^2 + x == y` as the first argument and use it first `Part` as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) in `RegionPlot`:

```
 RegionPlot[1 >= x^2 + x > y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1, Blue],
  PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> None,
  Epilog -> ContourPlot[ x^2 + x == y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed]][[1]]]
```

[image]